# Unable to find explicit activity class {}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml,my android manifest file read like this

Tags: android, xml

<--     I m getting this fatal error which occurred while trying to upload pictures for my app in the android studio.please help get rid of this error.whats the best solution? the error is: Unable to find explicit activity class {}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml -->>

```
----------


----------


: Unable to find explicit activity class {}; have you declared this
```

activity in your AndroidManifest.

```
    <?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <manifest XML ns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
    <uses-permission                android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"         />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>






<application
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: When is this happening? Compile time? Run time?

Comment: You probably have bug in calling gallery or photo activity. Put your activity/fragment code where you fetch images.

Comment: @theblitz during runtime i getting this error

Comment: @tompadre i m new  to android development please direct me to correct this error,i got all this source code from github

Comment: Can you post the code where this is happening

Comment: Then put that gitihub link

Answer (score 0):

You have to check a package where MainActivity is placed. It should be `com.parse.starter`. It seems MainActivity is in other place and you are getting an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you say copy and paste an activity instead of adding it via Android Studio. Basically it just means you'll need to add this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".your-activity-class-name"></activity>
```